# SQL Retrieve value from another table through id and display the total

Tags: mysql, sql

Retrieve value from another table through id and display the total (iterating table1 by getting the id and getting the value from table2 based on the id)

Scenario - get the sum of the invoice id 987

pid amount is in table 2, i want to get the total of 987

table 1
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ljpl.png)
[image]

table 2
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coYTc.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this -

$sql = "SELECT SUM(t1.Amount) FROM t1 LEFT JOIN e1 ON t1.PID = e1.PID WHERE e1.InvoiceID='987' GROUP BY e1.InvoiceID";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, sum(b.amount)
FROM e1 a
INNER JOIN t1 b ON a.pid = b.pid
group by a.id;
```